# Add elements form List A to element of list B where special member is equal

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add objects from one list, to a member of an object in another list in Java.
The objects to add have a member which identifies the unique element in the other list.

Is there a easy way to do so?

e.g. add every sailor to his ship in a list representing the fleet.

```java
class Sailor{
 Integer ship_id;
}

class Ship {
 Integer ship_id;
 List<Sailor> sailors;
}

List<Sailor> sailors;
List<Ship> fleet;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to create an association from the Id to the actual `Ship` object.

For instance, you can have a `Map<Integer, Ship>` somewhere on your code (this depends on the structure, can even be as a static member of `Ship`.

Having this `Map`, it's simply a matter of iteration your `Sailors`, and adding to the corresponding `Ship`.

```
Map<Integer, Ship> shipMap = ....;

for(Sailor sailor: sailors) {
    shipMap.get(sailor.shipId()).addSailor(sailor);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> add every sailor to his ship in a list representing the fleet.

Not quite sure what this means, but if you override equals and ahscode correctly (consistent, transistive, symmetric, relfexive). You can then just use [List.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to check if an object is in a list.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need something like below:

```
//Add every sailor to his ship in a list representing the fleet.
    public void addSailorToFleet(){
        for(Sailor sailor : sailors){
            for(Ship ship : fleet){
                if(sailor.ship_id == ship.ship_id){
                    ship.sailors.add(sailor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This has O(n^2) complexity.

The other solution using Map to store references(by pcalcao) trades off space for time. Depending on your context you can choose either.

The other disadvantage of using Map to store references is that you will always need to keep your Map updated on addition of new Ships.